# How to use a global variable's content inside a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json data coming from a mysql database, i was planning to plot it in a graph, but i got this problem utilizing the data given.

points i did..

- i already declared a global variable which is

  var data2 = '';
  var labels2 = '';
- my data coming from the database is doing well

  $.get("http://myurl/dashboard/numberabsencesgraph", function(data){
    codessss
   }

the problem and i got stuck here..

- labels: /*label location here*/ ,
  i want that ***labels2*** content be substituted on ***/*label location here*/***
  and ***data2*** content be substituted on ***/*data2 location here*/***

this is my code...

```
$(function () {
          var data2 = '';
          var labels2 = '';

          $.get("http://myurl/dashboard/numberabsencesgraph", function(data){
          //$(".numemployee").html(data.mycount);
          // beepPop.play();
          //$('.spinner-border').hide();
           for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            data2 += data[i].number+',';
            labels2 += ' "'+data[i].absentThisDays+'",';
           }
          data2 = data2.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
          // data2 content is [1,22,33,44]

          labels2 = '['+labels2.replace(/,\s*$/, "")+']';

          //labels2 content is ["somedate","somedate","somedate","somedate"]
          // iwant to put this in label location below
          var LINECHARTEXMPLE   = $('#lineChartExample');

          var lineChartExample = new Chart(LINECHARTEXMPLE, {
              type: 'line',
              options: {
                  legend: {labels:{fontColor:"#777", fontSize: 12}},
                  scales: {
                      xAxes: [{
                          display: true,
                          gridLines: {
                              color: '#fff'
                          }
                      }],
                      yAxes: [{
                          display: true,
                          ticks: {
                              max: 100,
                              min: 20
                          },
                          gridLines: {
                              color: '#fff'
                          }
                      }]
                  },
              },
              data: {

                  // labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],

                  labels: /*label location here*/ ,
                  datasets: [
                      {
                          label: "Data",
                          fill: true,
                          lineTension: 0.3,
                          backgroundColor: gradient1,
                          borderColor: 'rgba(210, 114, 181, 0.91)',
                          borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                          borderDash: [],
                          borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                          borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                          borderWidth: 2,
                          pointBorderColor: gradient1,
                          pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                          pointBorderWidth: 2,
                          pointHoverRadius: 5,
                          pointHoverBackgroundColor: gradient1,
                          pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                          pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                          pointRadius: 1,
                          pointHitRadius: 10,
                          // data: [0, 50, 33, 71, 49, 55, 35, 40, 30, 50, 25, 40],
                          data: /*data2 location here*/,
                          spanGaps: false
                      }
                  ]
              }
          });

          },"json");
**strong text**
```

Comment: Why is your **data** declaring **variables**?

Comment: `labels: labels2` ?!

Comment: @AndréPena declared global variable so that i may use it later down below the scripts..

Comment: with your local variables data2 and label2 you locally hide the global variables for the scope of the function. If you just comment those lines out it will use the values from the variables in global scope.

Comment: @JonasWilms the labels content is  ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] from the database and i want it to be posted somewhere in /*label location here*/ middle part of the code

Comment: @jallmer.. you mean i have to comment out or not declare a global variable?..i tried to alert() data2  and labels2 and i got what i want(its data). the problem is how im going to pass that data to substituted in the later part of the code.. somewhere  in  /*label location here*/ and /*data2 location here*/. if in php i just code like this "echo data2 ;" or "echo labels2 ;"

Comment: What don't you understand about my answer? Can I explain something better?

Comment: @bambam the answer is related but the problem is how im going to use the content of of data2 from (data2.push(data[i].number)) to be substituted on the later part of the code that needs it (/*data2 location here*/)

Comment: Saying you created global variables is misleading as a) you don't provide a global scope and be the variable definitions are local to $() {..} and thus not global. In case you would have global variables, you would need to think about the scope of variables with the same name.

Comment: @jallmer thanks for the tip. learning here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some very strange things here

```
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    data2 += data[i].number+',';
    labels2 += ' "'+data[i].absentThisDays+'",';
}

data2 = data2.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
// data2 content is [1,22,33,44] <---- A string!!!!
labels2 = '['+labels2.replace(/,\s*$/, "")+']';
// labels2 content is ... also a string
```

**We don't create arrays like that. What you create is a string** (that looks remotely like an array), the chart will expect a real array or object though.

What you need to do instead is to create an array and push to that.

```
var data2 = [];
var labels2 = [];

for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    data2.push(data[i].number);
    labels2.push(data[i].absentThisDays);
}
```

Then get rid of the replace functions...

You can then simply use that in your chart creation process

```
// ...
labels: labels2,
data: data2,
// ...
```

Note that there's no reason to create the variables outside of `$.get`

Comment: Intentionally its a string, and i formatted it just as what the sample code needed, the format is ... labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] and // data: [0, 50, 33, 71, 49, 55, 35, 40, 30, 50, 25, 40],

Comment: Probably, the last part of the answer is what you need (labels: labels2,). Replace this: labels: /*label location here*/ ,

Comment: The chart expects an array of labels, not a string! @oscar1925

Comment: @bambam lol at myself, i just missed it...  chart expects an array of labels, not a string indeed  thanks a lot....